# Select element with similar id using regex - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

An example of the element I need to select.

```
$("#edit_profile_form_profile_person_affiliations_2_user");
```

Id is same but a number of the element will change. 
I want to select all elements. Is this is possible with the id of elements?

Comment: Keyword: Attribute selector

Comment: Or better yet, use DOM traversal and/or classes, if possible.

Comment: Look at the list of [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) You'll find what you are looking for

Comment: You can select them by another attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("[id^=edit_profile_form_profile_person_affiliations_]")
```

It will match id's that start with "edit_profile_form_profile_person_affiliations_".

Answer (score 1):

As answer above,

```
$("[id^=edit_profile_form_profile_person_affiliations_]")
```

this is good to check if ID starts with

and this to check for end if ID

```
$("[id$=_user]");
```